# Using edgeLoopFromRect in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a impenetrable border at the edge of the game scene frame.

In Swift I have attempted to re-write this as:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRect(x: 0,y: 100,width: self.frame.size.width,height: self.frame.size.height-200))

}
```

Instead of giving me a clear boundary at the edge of frame it is providing a weak border, which my player (with no specified mass) can pass over.

I'm also not sure why I am having to subtract and add to the y axis to get the correct border but this is less of a concern. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is your scene is being loaded from an `sks` file? check the size of the scene in that file as it may be too big. have you set the `collisionBitMask`s on your player and edge. check your tags, this question has nothing to do with the image edge-detaction for that tag.

Comment: Thanks Okapi. I'm not loading from an sks file. And I haven't set collisionBitMasks yet, do I need to for the edge?

Comment: The `collisionBitMask` default value is set to collide with all other physics bodies. Does your sprites have physics bodies? Are you moving them with a force, impulse, or setting their velocities?

Comment: Thanks @Ox141E My sprites have physics bodies and I am moving my player with SKAction.moveTo(location, duration: )

Comment: The key is to move your sprites by applying a force or impulse so that they respond correctly to 1) collisions with physics bodies (such as an edge loop), and 2) forces such as linear/angular damping, friction, and force fields.

Comment: Thank you @0x141E I have changed the movement to be based on physics force and that has solved the problem.

Comment: @0x141E Could you please post this comment as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to move your sprites by applying a force/impulse or by setting the velocity property so that they respond correctly to

1. collisions with other physics bodies (such as an edge loop)
2. forces such as linear/angular damping, friction, and force fields.

Answer (score 2):

You should first define a bitmask category to represent the physics body of your game scene. I typically use the 32-bit binary value `00000000000000000000000000000001`, which I define as a constant:

```
let SCENE_EDGE_CATEGORY: UInt32 = 0x1
```

With that constant defined, you can now define the scene's physics body in a very readable way:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = SCENE_EDGE_CATEGORY
```

For any sprite that you want to be constrained by the edge of the scene, set its physics body's collision bitmask to the scene's category bitmask. You're telling Sprite Kit that you want the physics engine to handle collisions between that sprite and the scene's edge:

```
someSprite.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = SCENE_EDGE_CATEGORY
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This just shows up as an error for an expected declaration on the second line

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override init(size: CGSize)
    {
    super.init(size: size)
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))     
    anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
    }
```

works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely help you to define the edge of the screen in Swift.

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```